# Retrieving last year's data only if a single record for last month

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have two tables

`USER` and `TRANSACTION`

i want to choose the data from `TRANSACTION` table for last one year if the `USER` has made any transaction in the last month

`USER` and `TRANSACTION` table are connected using `USER_ID`

how can it will be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  trx_detail_1,
  trx_detail_2
from ( 
  select sum(
           case when trx_date > add_months(sysdate, -1) then 1 else 0 end
         ) over (partition by user_id) sum_user_last_month,
         trx_detail_1,
         trx_detail_2
     from 
         transaction
     where
         trx_date > add_months(sysdate, -12)
)
where 
     sum_user_last_month > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

list last year of transactions for users active in the last month:

(you don't need `USERS` table)

```
SELECT * 
FROM
TRANSACTIONS
WHERE transaction_date > sysdate - interval '1' year
  and user_id in 
    (select user_id
     from TRANSACTIONS
     where transaction_date > sysdate - interval '1' month);
```